# In Mongodb, how do I first sort by score, then sort by time if there is a "tie"?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pymongo, database

```
results = docDB.posts.find({"active":True }).sort("pop_score", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

This is my sort right now. But the problem is, some things have the same "score". In that case, if they tie, I want them to sort by "time" within the ones who tied.

How do I do that? It's possible to do that in Mysql...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can sort by more than one attribute at a time. e.g.

```
sort({name : 1, age : -1})
```

will sort by name ascending then by age descending

See here for reference: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

Edit:

In pymongo, that would be

```
.sort([['name', pymongo.ASCENDING], ['age', pymongo.DESCENDING]])
```

referenceL http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort

Comment: How would you write that query in Pymongo?  Pymongo doesn't accept a dictionary. It accepts 2 arguments

Comment: According to the documentation, pymongo sort can take a list of key value pairs to sort http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort